# Why does this syntactic element not get properly highlighted by matlab-prettifier?

Tags: listings, matlab

I've found that the `matlab-prettifier` does not highlight all the syntax compared to the original file.  For example, here is a snapshot of part of the file I am trying to include in my document from MATLAB:

[image]

As you can see, the "syms" variables show up like how a text command in MATLAB would look like.  However, from my code below, this MATLAB command is not colored typeset like the original.  How I can get this "sys" syntax in MATLAB to show up correctly in my LaTeX document?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mat1.m}
%% Variables to solve
syms r2s r3s th1 th2;

% arm1
x1 = [0 0]; y1 = [0 1];
x2 = [0 1]; y2 = [1 1];
x3 = [1 1]; y3 = [1 2];

% Size figure and draw arms
figure('position', [800, 300, 600, 550]);
hold on
plot(xcirc, ycirc,'m','linewidth', 1);
\end{filecontents}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Matlab Algorithm}}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!05},
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\mlttfamily\small,
caption={Draw a simple Fig.},
label={mat1}
]{mat1.m}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is discussed in the [`matlab-prettifier` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/matlab-prettifier); what we have here is an "unquoted string". These will occur not only for the `syms` function, but anywhere a function is used without parentheses delimiting its argument(s). In these cases, MATLAB treats the rest of the line, excluding any trailing semicolon, as a sequence of string arguments to the function (space-delimited). (That is, `legend a b` is equivalent to `legend('a','b')`.)

The developer of `matlab-prettifier` mentions in the to-do list that he plans to add automatic highlighting of unquoted strings in a future release.

Unfortunately, the only solution at this time is to add non-printing delimiters to the listing and tell `matlab-prettifier` about them using the `mlunquotedstringdelim` key. You should select a character that is not used elsewhere in the code—here I have chosen `þ`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily,
  mlunquotedstringdelim={þ}{þ},
]
%% Variables to solve
syms þr2s r3s th1 th2þ;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I trimmed down your code to show the crux of the issue succinctly. Note also that you must do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for `\mlttfamily` to work correctly.

This is less than ideal, because these extra characters must be added to the code, but until automatic handling of unquoted strings is added, this is the only way I have found to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Paul. Let me weigh in on this. Unfortunately, the Mathworks have never, as far as I know, released a proper language specification (including a grammar) for MATLAB. Therefore, most of `matlab-prettifier` is the result of reverse engineering on my part. One reason I still haven't got around implementing automatic highlighting of unquoted strings in `matlab-prettifier` is that those syntactic elements work in undocumented and somewhat mysterious ways... `:(`